# Proving group homorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is an abelian group and $n \in N$ show that $\phi :G \rightarrow G$ defined by $g \rightarrow g^n$ is a group homorphism

Answer (score 4):

Hint: does $\phi (ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$ for all $a, b \in G$?  If so, then $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

We know $\phi(g) = g^n$ for all $g \in G$.  We also know $G$ is abelian.  At this point, we are close to the answer.  Perhaps elaborate on where you are getting stuck?

Comment: Hum, I don't know how to proceed after saying $G$ is abelian

Comment: Well, $\phi(ab) = (ab)^n$.  Further, $\phi(a)\phi(b)=a^nb^n$.  Write these out and see if you can get one to equal the other.

Comment: Ah yes! I see it. Thank you for your help! I'm an undergraduate myself.